# Bootstrap vs Own Media Queries (HTML Impact)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I've been recently learning about Responsive Design more in detail.

I have used Bootstrap and continue to use it but I came to a point that I'm wondering Pros/Cons and effect on HTML cleanliness and readability (and whether it impacts performance)

Here is what I came to question but haven't found an answer.

With bootstrap, it seems that I need to declare the same section of HTML multiple times, so that I can apply the respective StyleSheets for the media screen size.

```
<section class="col-md-8">... more html ...</section>
<section class="col-sm-8">... same HTML above or slightly modified ...</section>
<section class="col-xs-12">... similar idea to sm-8 ... </section>
```

Whereas with straight Media Queries I could have

```
<section class="my-section> ... some html ... </section>

And then the media queries
@media screen and (max-width: 825px)
    section.my-section { ...adjustment... }
@media screen and (max-width: 760px)
    section.my-section { ...adjustment... }
@media screen and (max-width: 625px)
    section.my-section { ...adjustment... }
```

These media screen could be separated into respective separate files to keep the code cleaner and more self-contained

---

**So, Given that writing our own media queries require more time and effort, in your experience, what is a better choice, or under which circumstances?** (*say, small projects vs very large projects with multiple people working on it*)

**Or are there better practices for Bootstrap that make it better to avoid this HTML duplicated/triplicated/etc html code.**

**Does the HTML code duplication have an impact on performance, considering that sometimes very large data can be presented.** (*say using a framework like Angular to iterate and render a list of elements, and thus will have to create the elements for each of the media screen sections declared using bootstrap*)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bootstrap you call all the classes on the same element to give it responsiveness, not create separate divs for each:

```html
<section class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
 YOUR CONTENT HERE
</section>
```

Try not to duplicate your html content, though sometimes you just have to when there's no other way.

Comment: Ahhhh, I was not aware that you could do that. Thank you so much